# fetching various data corresponding to a tweet

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to fetch data from twitter for processing. Please see the code I want various data corresponding to a particular tweet corresponding to a given topic. I am able to fetch data (created_at, text,  username, user_id). It shows error when i try to fetch(location, followers_count, friends_count, retweet_count).

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json

ckey = '***********************'
csecret = '************************'
atoken ='*************************'
asecret = '**********************'

class listener(StreamListener):

  def on_data(self,data):
    try:
         all_data = json.loads(data)

         tweet = all_data["text"]

         username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]

         timestamp = all_data["created_at"]

         user_id = all_data["id_str"]

         location = all_data["location"]

         followers_count = all_data["followers_count"]

         friends_count = all_data["friends_count"]

         retweet_count = all_data["retweet_count"]

         saveThis = str(time.time())+'::'+timestamp+'::'+username+'::'+user_id+'::'+tweet+'::'+followers_count+'::'+friends_count+'::'+retweet_count+'::'+location
         saveFile = open('clean2.txt','a')
         saveFile.write(saveThis)
         saveFile.write('\n')
         saveFile.close
         return True
     except BaseException, e:
         print 'failed on data,',str(e)
         time.sleep(5)

 def on_error(self, status):
     print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["tweepy"])#topic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it fails on `all_data["location"]` is that tweets don't have such a property: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets

- same with friends_count, followers_count - they are properties of users, not tweets.

The code should not be failing on `all_date["retweet_count"]` as tweets have such a property.

P.S. please include the error message (even if you skip the full error trackback) when reporting errors. makes it's easier to help you, otherwise one has to guess what the error might be.

Comment: thanks it helped a lot. I got retweet_count as such. For followers_count I used followers_count = str(all_data["user"]["followers_count"]) and similarly for other 3......